# Inject @Context values into regular beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to inject `@Context` values into regular spring beans (not Jax-Rs resources or providers)?

[JERSEY-469](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-469) would suggest it can be done, but when I view it in debugger the fields are null (I'm checking this well after creation, this is not a problem with `InitializingBean`, I can't get the field injected at all).

```
@Component 
@Scope("prototype")
public final class TaskDO { 

@Context private ResourceContext resourceContext;
@FormParam("xml") private String xml;

}
```

Comment: AFAIK a setup like you describe will not work in Spring. Spring injects all the class dependencies during the container setup, not during each request. However in web contexts spring gives the ability to "inject" a number of useful request related context objects in the controller handler method. For example if you want the `HttpServletRequest` all you have to do is add it as an argument to the controller method

Comment: @geoand "Spring injects all the class dependencies during the container setup" - not true, e.g. for prototype scope; "ability to "inject" a number of useful request related context objects in the controller handler method." how is this relevant for injecting into regular beans?

Comment: `prototype` beans all also setup during the container setup. The difference between `prototype` and `singleton` is just that in the latter there is only one bean while in the former there could be more. Their initialization-injection in both cases happens when the bean is constructed

Comment: What is your definition of a regular bean? My understanding of the question was that you wanted to perform JAX-RS style injection into a Spring Controller. My answer was simply that Spring provides "injection" into various types of beans by the means of providing the arguments to the method